# How to extract the success or failure from the result of 'optimize' in Julia Optim.jl

Tags: optimization, julia

I ran several optimization problem with different models, but some of them doesn't seem to actually calculate the result but spit out some random results.
So, I would like to know how to extract the status of the 'optimize' results but cannot know easily.
I know if we just call the object of the 'optimize' then it shows the status, but I would like to call it and assign it to a column of data frame.
For example if the code for calling the status of success or failure is `status`, I would expect to call the result is

```
Object = optimize(function(x),x,LBFGS(); autodiff = :forward
result = Object.status
```

Is this possible? Can someone help with this?

I would expect a exact code to do this.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't really work (even parantheses are not balanced). I think you may be looking for the `converged(res)` function.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But I don't see how `converged' function works. In my julia it says it is not defined. Is the function defined in Optim.jl?

Comment: Yes, it is defined in Optim.jl. See `converged(res)` in https://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/stable/#user/minimization/ . If the code in your question was actually runnable or at least valid, you would get better/quicker answers.

Comment: Oh, I found out that if I use Optim.converged(res), then now it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Dan Getz got it right. I can use `Optim.converged(res)`.